# MySQL with PHP error

Tags: php, mysql

My database cannot be updated and giving this error. plz help

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`arasdb`.`saledetail`, CONSTRAINT `FK_saledetail_1` FOREIGN KEY (`saleid`) REFERENCES `sale` (`saleid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Comment: Please show the ddl and your update stament.

Answer (score 0):

which row you are trying to update, does not exist in master table, if you want to still update this row then set foreign_key_checks=0 and again 1. But you should correct your data.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have set relation in your database and the query you are trying to execute now is against the relation

Answer (score 0):

The message is clear.

When you update, you try to set a value for "saleid" which doesnt exist in table "sale".

Be sure "saleid" is defined in your update.
Your value may be null, so update cant work.